# jquery select visible without using :visible

Tags: jquery, visible

from jquery docs an element is hidden when : An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

I have a hidden div and inside paragraphs that can be either hidden or visible

```
<div id="wrapper"> <-- this is hidden -->
    <p class="myclass" style=">display:none">text</p> 
    <p class="myclass">text</p> 
    <p class="myclass" style=">display:none">text</p> 
    <p class="myclass">text</p> 
</div>
```

So any selection $(".myclass:visible") fails because wrapper is hidden

Is there any other way to check if are visible elements inside wrapper and count them.

For example check if element has class myclass and css display:none is one solution i guess but any tries from me are failed.

Any help appreciated

Comment: means u want that in hidden div (id=wrapper) have two visible element with given  class `myclass`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I see is to add a custom class that hides elements (instead of inline style):

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

<div id="wrapper"> <-- this is hidden -->
    <p class="myclass hidden"text</p> 
    <p class="myclass" >text</p> 
    <p class="myclass hidden">text</p> 
    <p class="myclass" >text</p> 
</div>
```

Then you can count the "visible" ones with `$('.myclass:not(.hidden)').length`.

---

**Update:**

If you actually only have to find the elements which `display` property is not `none`, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) could do the job:

```
var count = $('.myclass').filter(function() {
    return this.style.display !== "none";    
}).length;
```

Of course this won't work if some elements have `display:none` set by you and not by the UI tabs plugin. But it might be sufficient in your situation.

Comment: @Felix good thinking but this is a hidden jquery ui tab and i have to parse on some event

Comment: @ntan: I don't understand. You mean you cannot influence the whether the style is set inline or adding a class?

Comment: @Felix the style="display:none" is added by the ui tabs not be me ( i mean the tab panel is not selected)

Comment: @Felix seems elegant i will give it a try

Comment: $('.myclass:not([style*="display: none"])')

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Felix's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015510/jquery-select-visible-without-using-visible/5015559#5015559).

But if you really want an alternative without changing your markup, this should work:

```
var wrapper, visibles;
wrapper = $("#wrapper");
wrapper.show();
visibles = wrapper.find(":visible");
wrapper.hide();
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/alase4)

As long as you don't have a yield in there (`setTimeout`, etc.), odds are high the browser won't actually show anything during the brief interval in which the wrapper is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the display property directly, eg:

```
$('#wrapper p.myclass').each(function(){
 alert($(this).attr('style'));
}
```

will show you the value of the style attribute.

you can also do

`this.style.display` to access the display property directly.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
alert ( $("#wrapper .myclass:visible").size());
```

Result was 2 when I tried it :)

Comment: Was your `wrapper` element hidden? (E.g., with a CSS rule.) Apparently his is.

Comment: @Anriette, @Brian: Doesn't work when you actually do what the OP said and make sure the wrapper is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/P9gth/4/

Comment: @T.J. Yeah, I saw, I added the CSS in this one http://jsfiddle.net/AnrietteC/P9gth/7/ and yeah, it didn't work.

Comment: You mean you got `2` even when the wrapper was hidden? You have two counterexamples now that show it does not work ;)